# Consuming SOAP service by dependency injection

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, inversion-of-control

I've been developing  silveright app which consumes some WCF services. In my WCF, i have several different services that implement the same interface for example:

```
public class Service1 : IService<Type1> {...}
public class Service2 : IService<Type2> {...}
```

I've been thinking about acceesing the `IService` interface from the client app (consumer) to developer a generic class to maximize code re-use for consuming the WCF services for example:

```
public class MyUnitedOPs<T>  {

      ServiceReference.IService<T> _object;
      public MyUnitedOPs (ServiceReference.IService<T> _object) {
          this._object = _object;
      }
}
```

But, apparently I can't directly access the `IService` interface and it is known as `IServiceOf_Service1` for instance. Although this can be still cast but the methods that I get from this `IServiceOf_Service1` are different from ones that are provided in the service that implements it for example I have `BeginAdd` and `EndAdd` while in the service that implements it, I have just an `AddAsync` method.

So, out of curiosity, is it possible at all to do something like this ?

Comment: How do you generate your proxy?

Comment: After 3 readings I think finally understand your question. This isn't Dependency Injection. This is "SOAP client can't reuse base interface hierarchy defined by the service". Right?

Comment: @ErnieL: yeah exactly

Answer (score 2):

You can't make your IService<T> traverse to the client, as this is not supported by WSDL.

However, here are a few things that you can do:

1. You can have a generic service contract on the server side.
2. You can also have a generic service implementation on the server side.
   (you didn't have to create Service1 and Service2, you could stick with Service<T>)
3. You can host multiple ***concrete*** instances of your generic service, each with different type.
4. The client can reference one or more of your hosted services, and for each it will produce ***concrete*** proxies.
5. The reason you're seeing the BeginAdd and EndAdd is just a technicality of the ***client*** side, it does not affect ***anything*** happening on the server. From your post, i take it that your Add operation returns a Task, which is an efficient asynchronous implementation of a WCF service, starting from .net 4.5. Even though your operation returns a Task, if you'll check the WSDL generated by the service, you'll see that your operation actually returns something else (an int, or string, or maybe some DataContract, depending on your implementation). That's because asynchronicity, is just an implementation detail of the service, and it doesn't change the ***contract***. The client can call your service in three different ways:

   a. Just call it directly. Meaning the your client will ***block*** the current thread.

   b. Use the APM async model, which utilizes methods like BeginXXX and EndXXX, which will initiate the actuall I/O request over the network, from a different thread, ***not blocking*** the calling thread like the previous option.

   c. Use the TAP async model, which utilizes Tasks with methods like XXXAsync.

   You control these options (a - c), and many others (for example, what collection types to use for collections? Arrays? List? etc') from the "Add Service Reference" window in visual studio.